# Sharing StorageItems from a byte[] array

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, sharing

I want to implement the Share source contract in my WinRT C# Metro app (Windows Release Preview). My app is storing arbitrary files. Not in the filesystem, but instead I get the data over a WCF service as `byte[]`. Now I want to share such "files" in my app.

The only possibility I've seen with a standard data format is using the `SetStorageItems()` method on the `DataPackage`. Thus I'm facing the challenge to convert the data from my byte array to a `StorageFile`, which can be shared. I found the `StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync()` method and wanted to use it in this way:

```
// filename: string
// fileContent: byte[]

// ... setting DataPackage title and description ...

DataRequestDeferral deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync(filename,
    async stream => await stream.WriteAsync(fileContent.AsBuffer()), null);
args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new List<IStorageItem> { file });

deferral.Complete();
```

It compiles fine, but it doesn't work as expected. I've tried the sharing with the standard Mail app. The Mail share view opens and I can create a new mail. The file is shown without thumbnail (as expected), but the e-mail can't be sent. It's showing the sending progress for several minutes and then an error occurs: "Couldn't share {filename} with Mail.". The share charm shows "Something went wrong" and "[...] Mail can't share right now. Try again later.".

It works perfectly when I load the `StorageFile` from the file system: the mail opens and is sent within seconds, no problems here. So either I'm using `CreateStreamedFileAsync()` wrong or there's a bug in this method, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback passed into CreateStreamedFileAsync, you need to actually dispose of the object - that signals to the OS that you are done.

Wrote a complete example [here](http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/how-to-use-createstreamedfileasync/)

Answer (score 0):

The Mail app is not a target for sharing files.  From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/06/14/building-the-mail-app.aspx: "Mail supports sharing text, links, and pictures."

Remember that there are 2 parts of the Share contract: Share sources and Share targets.  As you know, there are many different data formats that can be shared between them, like text, pictures, URIs, and files.  The full list of the different data formats that are supported is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771179.aspx.

I recommend that you use the Share Target Sample app to test that your file is being shared properly - share to this and it will display everything that is being shared from your app as a source (and it does accept files for sharing).  You can download it from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782.  You can also use the Share Source Sample app as an example and leverage code from this app; you can download it from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84.

Hope that helps!

Comment: As noted above: when I load the file from a physical folder, everything works fine. Thus I don't see the problem is in the contract itself, but in the provided data. Furthermore, the Mail app appears only as share target when I share StorageItems with the standard data format. If I want to share StandardDataFormats.Bitmap, the Mail app doesn't appear.

Comment: Is it just me having problems with the sample app "Sharing Content Target App" - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782 ? When I want to share content to this app, the sharing view appears for one second, then flickers one time and disappears. Is there a bug in this app? Maybe you can reproduce this issue...

Comment: Ah, I found the problem: the app must not run in order to get the sharing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, perhaps the preview version of the Mail app doesn't handle the sharing target contract correctly. Using the SDK sample app "Sharing Content Target App" from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782, sharing a StorageItem created in memory with the `StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync()` method posted above works fine.

Thus, that's the way you should go when you want to share in-memory `byte[]` arrays. For testing, make sure that the share target app doesn't run in Visual Studio when you want to share data from another app with it. Then the sharing sidebar mysteriously will disappear automatically...